# Convert a date into an integer in python

Tags: python, datetime, integer, comparison

I'am trying to convert a date to an integer for a comparison.

```
# Python3 code to calculate age in years
import datetime
from datetime import date

date_entry = input('Enter your birthdate in YYYY/MM/DD format: ')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('/'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)

def calculateAge(birthDate):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthDate.year - \
        ((today.month, today.day) < (birthDate.month, birthDate.day))

    return age

# Driver code
print(calculateAge(date1), "years")

if date1 < 18:
    print('You are under age')
    exit()
```

I have an error in my if statement because date1 is not an integer.
How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit as below.

```
if calculateAge(date1) < 18:
    print('You are under age')
    exit()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o48J0.png)

Comment: You're welcome, you wrote a nice code.